# unit of a ring distinct from neutral element in a subset-group

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we examine the set $H$ of square matrices of order $2$ of the form $ M(x) := \begin{pmatrix}
x & x \\
x & x 
\end{pmatrix}$, we notice that the identity matrix isn't there. but still this set has a neutral element with respect to matrix multiplication, that is $M\left(\frac 12 \right)$.

Now if we restrict ourselves to nonzero matrices, we see that this set is even a **group** under matrix multiplication though no matrix of $H$ is invertible in the usual sense.

I'd like to know how normal is this situation and look forward to get more information about that. Thanks.

Comment: Take two rings $R_1$ and $R_2$. Then $R_1\times R_2$ is a ring that contains $R_1$ and $R_2$ as subsets, but they do not contain the unit of $R_1\times R_2$. Looking at unit groups yields similar examples to yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can generate a large class of examples that includes this one.

First, a standard computation gives the Jordan form of the matrix $M(x)$ and the matrix via which it is similar to $M(x)$:
$$M(x) = \pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}}^{-1} \pmatrix{2x&0\\0&0}\underbrace{\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}}}_P .$$
The Jordan normal form suggests writing $M(\frac{1}{2} x) = P^{-1} \pmatrix{x&0\\0&0} P$, so we see immediately that
\begin{align}
M\left(\tfrac{1}{2} x\right) + M\left(\tfrac{1}{2} y\right)
&= P^{-1} \pmatrix{x&0\\0&0} P + P^{-1} \pmatrix{y&0\\0&0} P\\
&= P^{-1} \pmatrix{x + y&0\\0&0} P\\
&= M\left(\tfrac{1}{2}(x + y)\right)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
M\left(\tfrac{1}{2} x\right) M\left(\tfrac{1}{2} y\right)
&= P^{-1} \pmatrix{x&0\\0&0} P \cdot P^{-1} \pmatrix{y&0\\0&0} P \\
&= P^{-1} \pmatrix{x&0\\0&0} \pmatrix{y&0\\0&0} P \\
&= P^{-1} \pmatrix{x y&0\\0&0} P \\
&= M\left(\tfrac{1}{2} x y\right) .
\end{align}
Thus
$$x \mapsto M\left(\tfrac{1}{2} x\right)$$
is a ring homomorphism $$(\Bbb F, +, \cdot) \to \left(\left\{\pmatrix{x&x\\x&x}\right\}, +, \cdot\right) ,$$ where $\Bbb F$ is the field underlying the matrix ring (necessarily not of characteristic $2$, so that the element $\frac{1}{2}$ is available). It's easy to check that it is surjective, so this is actually a ring *isomorphism*.

Now, $+$ and $\cdot$ denote (the restrictions of) the usual matrix multiplication and addition map, but $\left(\left\{\pmatrix{x&x\\x&x}\right\}, +, \cdot\right)$ is *not* a subring of $M(2, \Bbb F)$, because (as you observed) the neutral elements are not the same. By varying the coefficient of $x$ in the Jordan normal form and varying $P$ among the invertible elements, we get a large family of rings, all isomorphic to $\Bbb F$.

*Much* more generally, a bijection $\Phi: R \to S$ between the set underlying a ring $(R, +, \cdot)$ and a set $S$ induces a ring structure $(\oplus, \odot)$ on $S$ by regarding $\Phi$ as an identification, namely defining, $$s \oplus s' := \Phi(\Phi^{-1}(s) + \Phi^{-1}(s')), \qquad s \odot s' := \Phi(\Phi^{-1}(s) \cdot \Phi^{-1}(s')) .$$ (Similar constructions work for any admissible algebraic structure.)
In our case, $R = \Bbb F$, $\Phi = M$ and $S = \Phi(R)$. (It is an instructive exercise to work out the rather peculiar-looking ring operations for the choices $R = S = \Bbb R$ and $\Phi : x \mapsto x - 1$, for example.)

What is relatively special about the class of examples constructed above is that the induced maps $\oplus$ and $\odot$ are restrictions of familiar operations, namely, matrix addition and multiplication.

Comment: Thanks. In the case where the unit of the subset-ring $H$  and that of the mother ring $R$ are distinct, if it happens that an element $M$ of the subset-ring has an inverse in the ring $(H,+,\times)$ that is distinct from an eventual inverse in $(R,+,\times)$ (same operations), asking for the inverse of $M$ without making mention of the context would be ambiguous.

Comment: Strictly speaking, they are *not* the same operations, since as maps they have different domains and codomains. But what you say is otherwise true: The inverse of an element with respect to an operation in general depends on the operation being used, so when there is more than one operation in play, saying "the inverse" without specifying the operation is generally ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what you mean by "how normal" it is (perhaps "how unusual"?) but I can assure you that this happens a lot more than you think.

The thing is that we are used to "nice" operations that we see every day. But really, if you had some group $G$, and a set $X$, you could take whatever arbitrary bijection you want $f:G\to X$ and make $X$ a group by declaring that

$x\cdot y:=f(f^{-1}(x) f^{-1}(y))$

(The dot is the new multiplication, juxtaposition denotes the old multiplication. The same thing works for rings, but of course you're transporting *both* operations.)  This is called transportation of structure from $G$ to $X$.

In particular, you could take the group of nonzero real numbers and the map $x\mapsto \frac{x}{2}$, and you get this perfectly defined group structure on the nonzero real numbers that has the peculiar identity:

$x\cdot\frac{1}{2}:=\frac{1}{2}(2x2\frac{1}{2})=x$.

Notice where the identity of the group of nonzero reals is being mapped: $1\mapsto \frac12$.

That's essentially what's happening here, except that it's disguised with matrix multiplication in $x\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}\frac{x}{2}&\frac{x}{2}\\ \frac{x}{2}&\frac{x}{2}\end{bmatrix}$.

The thing that makes this example somewhat striking is that the "weird" transported multiplication is linked with this ordinary multiplication (matrix multiplication.)

Actually, if you leave the zero matrix in, you'll find that this is a subring of $M_2(\mathbb R)$ that is (ring) isomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks, the other example I came across is actually the set $K$ of square matrices of  order 3 of the form $M(x,y) := \begin{pmatrix}
x & 0 & y \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
-2y & 0 & x+2y
\end{pmatrix}$. If we endow $K$ with usual matrix addition and multiplication operations, it acquires the structure of commutative field.

And in a problem, it was asked to give the inverse of a given matrix.

Here, the terminology "inverse" is confusing because no element of $K$ has a proper inverse vis-a-vis matrix multiplication.

Comment: I would say that $\left\{\pmatrix{x&x\\x&x}\right\}$ is *not* a subring of $M_2(\Bbb R)$, as they do not share the same identity element.

Comment: @Travis I would say that in noncommutative algebra that convention is not as common as in commutative algebra. But sure, one could also say it is just a ring contained in $M_2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @OussamaSarih That is because you are *looking for the wrong identity.* The identity of that ring is $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$, and the inverse is $\frac{1}{x^2+2xy+2y^2}\begin{bmatrix}x+2y&0&-y\\ 0&0&0\\ 2y&0&x\end{bmatrix}$, whenever at least one of $x,y$ is nonzero.

Comment: I got it for this specific example. 

The thing is that, if, assumingly, an element $M$ happens to have an inverse with respect to $\times$ in $\mathcal{M}_3(\mathbb{R})$ and an inverse with respect to $\times$ in $H$, \\
Would this be possible in some other situation (same operation $\times$) ? \\
If so then, asking for the "inverse" of such an element without further information would be ambiguous.

Comment: @rschwieb Interesting, I wasn't aware that this definition wasn't useful. At any rate, +1 for the quite nice answer.

Comment: @OussamaSarih In this case, it is impossible for one of these $M$'s to have an inverse in $M_3(\mathbb R)$: they clearly have determinant zero.  But like I said, you can bijectively map $M_3(\mathbb R)$ to itself in any way at all, and the resulting transported structure lets you name anything as the multiplicative identity, and the inverses change wildly.

Comment: @OussamaSarih You might consider working out how your $3\times 3$ ring here is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$. Finding a candidate for the imaginary unit is an interesting exercise.

Comment: @Travis Thanks!